# Unique Bluetooth identifier Xamarin iOS/Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

im making Xamarin Android/iOS application for COVID purposes, i need to detect when another devices are nearby to me (less than 1.5 meters), im calculating the distance with de RSSI, but on iOS i cant get unique identifier to know with ho im breaking the distance. Im new on iOS, i already tried the ble plugin but i doesnt get the name of the other devices. If i can get the bluetooth device name its okay for me.

i've already tried the peripheral.name with CoreBluetooth but its always null.

Comment: You should be aware that Apple will not accept tracing apps that are not submitted by a government health organisation. Also you would want to use an identifier created by your app rather than relying on the name of the device anyway. This is area has a lot of privacy issues. Apple and google have created a cross platform exposure tracing api that provides tracing in a privacy compatible way, but again it is only available to governments

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer, this app is for internal purposes we dont upload to any store. We cant get de device name with peripheral.name, and we cant find any static data displayed for the scan without pair the devices.

Comment: That is correct. Apple and Google have put a fair bit of work into protecting people’s privacy by limiting what is discoverable by passive scanning. You will need the devices to connect to exchange identifiers. You can look at some of the government apps that have had their source code released such as the Singapore Bluetrace and the Australian CovidSafe